# ProcessRequest Method

Tags: java, servlets

When do ProcessRequest method called?

I am having a hard time why ,what and how the process request is called? why it is called and how it was called by the servlet container.

Comment: What `ProcessRequest()` are you talking about? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: So I am generating JSON data from ajax request from a jsp page and calling a doPost method, can I use the ProcessRequest method instead of a doPost? thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `servlet` has two important methods for handling the client's request:

***`1. doPost: in general handles requests coming from forms with post method.`***

***`2. doGet: handled requests coming from get method.`***

Now, `ProcessRequest` method, is any other method that you can use into your code which is not bound (***overridden***) to anything.

It is called from the above methods to not complicate the code in them thus the requests are handled in it.

so you can use `ProcessRequest` to handle your request **if and only if** it's called from one of the methods above.

Comment: Ow right. :) now I fully understand it. thank you very much. this site really helps.

Answer (score 3):

The only [ProcessRequest](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/j2ee/servlet-basics.html) I could find, and the example includes this

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  processRequest(request, response);
}
```

and

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  processRequest(request, response);
}
```

So, it's called when you call it.

Comment: So meaning I can overload the porcessRequest Method everytime?

Comment: Implement. ProcessRequest is not in Servlet so you can't override it.