# japplet to servlet communication, servlet not reached

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, applet, japplet

I'm trying to send post data from my japplet to my servlet "Connexion" but the output that i placed in my servlet init method and processRequest method are never displayed in my console.

Here is the send method call in my japplet

```
 private void jButtonEntrerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    try {
        String infos = "login=" + URLEncoder.encode(FieldLogin.getText(), "UTF-8")
                + "&mdp=" + URLEncoder.encode(FieldMdp.getText(), "UTF-8")+"&action=Login";
    //"http://localhost:8088/Web_Applic_Achats_2/Connexion"

    SendPost("/Connexion", infos, getCodeBase());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The sendPost method definition (in abstract class Send)

```
 public static void SendPost(String dest, String infos, URL pageCourante)
{

    try {
        URL url = new URL (pageCourante, dest);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);

        try (OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter( connection.getOutputStream())) {
            out.write(infos);
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Err url: "+ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IO envoi: "+ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }        
}
```

And finally my servlet Connexion

```
public class Connexion extends HttpServlet{

BeanBDAccess bdAccess= null;
ServletContext sc;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("Hey init");
    try {
        bdAccess= new BeanBDAccessMysql("BD_SOCIETE", "root", "boulaite");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    sc = getServletContext();
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    if(bdAccess != null)
    {
        try {
            bdAccess.FermerConnectionBd();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    System.out.println("Hey processRequest");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    // .... code ....
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

I ran many test and noticed that i don't have my parameter or my complete request uri in the http server monitor (netbeans). 
But when i output the url in my applet the url is ok.

[http req](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM3Cq.png)

**Last edit:**

I don't know if it will change something but I noticed in the http server monitor that I'm getting a 304 statut: exit not modified

[http 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COLw1.png)

Comment: What is processRequest() method and how do you expect it to be called? Chnage this to doPost(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740077/processrequest-methodhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740077/processrequest-method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380413/paging-with-linq-for-objects doGet() and doPost() call processRequest(), they are generated by netbeans chan you create a servlet