# Why won't my servlet forward to my .jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Here is my code:

**Index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web App Assignment 5</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="listEmployees.jsp">View Employees</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Employees.java**

```
class Employees {

        private String name;
        private int id;

        public Employees() {

        }
        public Employees(String name, int id){
            setName(name);
            setID(id);
        }

        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }

        public int getID(){
            return id;
        }

        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setID(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

**getEmployees.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    public class getEmployees extends HttpServlet {

        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

            try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            Employees emp1 = new Employees("Jim", 002);
            Employees emp2 = new Employees("Pam", 043);
            Employees emp3 = new Employees("Dwight", 013);
            Employees emp4 = new Employees("Kevin", 123);
            Employees emp5 = new Employees("Michael", 001);
            Employees emp6 = new Employees("Oscar", 033);

            List<Employees> employees = new ArrayList<Employees>();
            employees.add(emp1);
            employees.add(emp2);
            employees.add(emp3);
            employees.add(emp4);
            employees.add(emp5);
            employees.add(emp6);

            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("empl", employees);

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("listEmployees.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                }
            }
    }
```

**listEmployees.jsp**

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>List of Employees </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><u> List of Employees </u> </h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>

                <td>Employee Name</td> 
                <td></td>
                <td>Employee ID</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <c:forEach items="${empl}" var="current">
        <tr>
          <td><c:out value="${empl}" /><td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get the index page to forward to the getEmployees servlet which is then supposed to forward the list of employees to the JSP and display the list of employees. I am unsure of why the servlet is not forwarding to the jsp. Any help would be much appreciated. Using Glassfish server.

Comment: can you seperate the code into code blocks each with the filename it belongs to ?

Comment: and remove "netbeans" from the title As I don't see the IDE relevant to the question here(what I think is relevant is the application server e.g GlassFish)

Comment: What actually happens?

Comment: When I run the code as is, it shows the html "Employee name" and "Employee ID" from the listEmployees.jsp but doesn't show the array from the servlet, which is what I'm trying to show

Answer (score 1):

You must change the variable that you are printing in the foreach:

```
<c:forEach items="${empl}" var="current">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${current.name}" /><td>
        <td><td>
        <td><c:out value="${current.id}" /><td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Without changing the variable either

Comment: According to his words you are right, then question title is obviously wrong

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpServlet` has two important methods for handling the client's request:

***`1. doPost: in general handles requests coming from forms with HTTP POST method`***

***`2. doGet: handled requests coming from get method.`***

Now, your `processRequest` method, is just your code which is not bound (***overridden***) to anything.

You can easily call it from the above methods in order to not complicate the code in them thus the requests are handled in it.

So in order to use `processRequest` to handle your request you have to **actually call it** from one of those two methods.

Just add to your Servlet those methods that are going to take the requests and regardless the request type they will execute `processRequest`

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  processRequest(request, response);
}
```

and

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  processRequest(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`processRequest` is not answering any requests himself, it is just support method, it will be executed upon request if and only if it was called from `doGet` or `doPost`, which are actually responding to requests, if you want to both methods execute same code, just call that `processRequest` from `doPost` and `doGet`, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740077/processrequest-method)

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown the content of your web.xml. But from the description of the problem, it sounds like your container is not able to find any servlet which is mapped to a url pattern like `/listEmployees.jsp`. No, `getEmployees` is not the servlet which will be called because it doesn't override the `doGet` or `doPost` method. You have one method called `processRequest`. But the container doesn't know what that method is. It only knows `doPost` or `doGet` or a `service` method none of which is overridden by your `getEmployees` servlet. It looks like (without seeing your `web.xml`), the container is simply dispatching the request to the JSP because of the settings in your web.xml. Do the following things to fix your problem:

1. Correct the settings in your `web.xml` to map the url pattern `/listEmployees.jsp` to a servlet with a servlet class of `getEmployees`.
2. Override `doGet` method in your `getEmployees` servlet and call the `processRequest` method from it.